# mysql не стартует

Tags: mysql

после команд

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT GMT | mysql -u root -p mysql
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC UTC | mysql -u root -p mysql
mysql -u root -p -e "flush tables;" mysql 
sudo service mysql restart
```

сервер перестал подниматься, можно ли удалить эти изменения?

пробую стартовать так

```
 /etc/init.d/mysql start 

    touch: cannot touch `/var/log/mysql/error.log': Permission denied
    chmod: cannot access `/var/log/mysql/error.log': Permission denied
    /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 129: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
    /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 1: eval: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
    touch: cannot touch `/var/log/mysql/error.log': Permission denied
    chown: cannot access `/var/log/mysql/error.log': Permission denied
    chmod: cannot access `/var/log/mysql/error.log': Permission denied
    /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 129: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
    ......
     * MySQL Community Server 5.6.33 did not start. Please check logs for more details.
```

Comment: В логах-то что?

Comment: @Мелкий
дополнил вопрос

Comment: @Мелкий в error.log пусто, остальные не генерируются, пробовал вручную делать touch и выдавать права, никакого эффекта

Comment: Запустите MySQL под root или выполните команду: sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

Comment: Была синтаксическая ошибка в файле etc/mysql/my.cnf

Исправил и все заработало

Answer (score 0):

Была синтаксическая ошибка в файле etc/mysql/my.cnf Исправил ее и все заработало.
Спасибо за помощь.